# Add additional multi factor options to ASP.net Core 2 Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am having trouble adding an additional multi factor option to the ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity template.  Out of the box it supports the Microsoft Authenticator app, but I also need it to support SMS.  It cannot be assumed that all of our users carry a smart phone.

Are there any good articles or samples that detail how to do this with the most current version of ASP.NET Identity?  The current sms example on Microsoft's sites deal with an older version of Identity.

Comment: Literally the first Google result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: That article deals specifically with .net core 1.x.  My question has to deal with .net core 2.0.   The first line of the article/tutorial states this.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't actually read the article. However, after now reading the document, I'm reasonably sure it's simply cautioning you away from this particular approach. 2FA via SMS has been shown to be vulnerable, so authenticator apps really are the best option currently. However, none of the code there is truly deprecated by ASP.NET Core 2.0, so the tutorial is actually still applicable.

Comment: Not a problem.  I unfortunately cannot guarantee that all my users have access to a device capable of running the authenticator apps. I was hoping that someone out in the wild had added in sms to the most recent identity templates.